# Flutter and Getx: How an observable emit changes

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, flutter-getx

I have a little bar that changes color when the user move the container and when the user stop touching the container. I´m using a Listener widget and the functions onPointerMove which calls a GetxController with value of true and onPointerUp with value of false so the color of the container changes according to a RxBool in the controller.
My question is: while calling onPointerMove the RxBool changes to a true value but I don´t know if the value is always emitted even though it´s the same, because then my widget will redraw every time; or if the value doesn´t emmit anything because it´s the same.

Here is the controller

```
  RxBool isPressing = false.obs;

  void changeColor(bool i) => i ? isPressing.value = true : isPressing.value = false;
```

Here is the listener widget

```
 Listener(
      onPointerMove: (PointerEvent e) => _touchController.changeColor(true),
      onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent e) => _touchController.changeColor(false),
      .
      .
      .
          children: [
            Obx(() => Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 4,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _touchController.isPressing.value ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
            )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn the Container in a StatelessWidget and print something in the build method, you may notice that it's not emitted when the value is the same.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MainController _touchController = Get.put(MainController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Listener(
        onPointerMove: (PointerEvent e) =>
            _touchController.changeColor(true),
        onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent e) =>
            _touchController.changeColor(false),
        child: Obx(() => Box(
          isPressing: _touchController.isPressing.value,
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isPressing;

  const Box({Key? key, required this.isPressing}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('re build');
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isPressing ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isPressing = false.obs;

  void changeColor(bool i) =>
      i ? isPressing.value = true : isPressing.value = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you´re right. I was wondering how could I print something but my brain crashed. Thank you again